# Allocating a custom IP as Elastic IP in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Initially I have an elastic IP - `52.XX.XX.XX` which is associated to an instance. But, accidentally when the instance got terminated the elastic IP got released. Now, Is there any possibility to obtain the same IP - `52.XX.XX.XX` when I allocate the new elastic IP instead of randomly generating the IP.

Comment: When instance gets terminated the elastic IP is just disassociated not released, did you check you elastic IPs if it is there?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it. It is not there in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the address was released there is nothing you can do, since it is probably already allocated to another AWS user. You should design your environment so that it does not depend on any one specific IP address.